# predict_classes() deprecated in R, what to use instead?

Tags: r, keras, conv-neural-network, prediction, predict

I've created a CNN in RStudio using keras to predict MNIST digits. I am now trying to predict with this model using the following code

```
cnn_pred <- cnn_model %>%
    predict_classes(x_test)
```

but predict_classes() has been deprecated and I need something to replace it. I've tried using just predict() but it results in continuous predictions when I need it to predict what the digit is (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, or 9).

What function can be used with the CNN model to give a categorical prediction?

Answer (score 1):

This is a convoluted way, but I managed to get it to work. I first had to get the array from the tf object, which turned out to be a python array, so then had to convert it to R object. And then I could compare/do calculations on that against another r object.

This is the prediction on the test data, output (`prednn.tf`) is a tensor:

```
prednn.tf <- modelnn %>% predict(x_test) %>% k_argmax()
```

Now convert from tensor to an array using np_array:

```
prednn.array <- np_array(prednn.tf)
```

Now to a r-object:

```
prednn.array <- reticulate::py_to_r(prednn.array)
```

Now compare the prediction against actual and calculate the accuracy:

```
accuracy(prednn.array, g_test)
```

**Note** - following is the accuracy function:

```
accuracy <- function(pred, truth)
  mean(drop(pred) == drop(truth))
```

All this because `predict_classes()` is deprecated. There might be an easier way, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
cnn_pred <- cnn_model %>%
    predict(x_test) %>% k_argmax()
```

Comment: how do I view the numbers that the model predicted?

Answer (score 0):

In my example, seems an even easier method was to do this:

change accuracy function from:

```
accuracy <- function(pred, truth)
  mean(drop(pred) == drop(truth))
```

to:

```
accuracy <- function(pred, truth)
  mean(drop(as.numeric(pred)) == drop(truth))
```

and then the following works:

```
modelnn %>% predict(x_test) %>% k_argmax() %>% accuracy(g_test)
```

so it seems, `as.numeric()` will take the tensor and extract the values. Hope this helps!